# How to update variable in JS

Tags: javascript, ajax

How can i update variable from function?
I have this. But both variables still "0" after "updateFilter()".
How can i do this without run "loadAjax(var1, var2)" from slider function?

```
var var1 = 0,
    var2 = 0;

$("#slider").slider({
    // options...
    stop: function( event, ui ) {
        var var1 = ui.values[ 0 ], // <- changes on move
            var2 = ui.values[ 1 ]; // <- changes on move
        updateFilter();
    }
});

function updateFilter() {
    loadAjax(var1, var2);
}
```

sorry for my english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem with you code is you are defining same varible you defined in global scope

```
var var1 = 0,
    var2 = 0;

//in function below you are redefining var1 and var2 varible please dont do that 
 stop: function( event, ui ) {
        var var1 = ui.values[ 0 ], // <- changes on move
            var2 = ui.values[ 1 ]; // <- changes on move
        updateFilter();
```

instead of above code stop method should be

```
 stop: function( event, ui ) {
            var1 = ui.values[ 0 ], // <- changes on move
            var2 = ui.values[ 1 ]; // <- changes on move
        updateFilter();
```

---

why dont you pass varible to function directly like this

```
updateFilter(var1, var2);


function updateFilter(var1, var2) {
    loadAjax(var1, var2);
}
```

Comment: Oh, thanks! It works (im new in JS and didn't know these details)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/kcg1hmsu/

your values are 0, because you're shadowing your global variables, you can simply remove the *var* inside the stop function

```
$("#slider").slider({
    // options...
    stop: function( event, ui ) {
         var1 = ui.values[ 0 ], // <- changes on move
         var2 = ui.values[ 1 ]; // <- changes on move
         console.log(var1, var2);
        updateFilter();
    }
});
```